# Acrobat JavaScript - Doc.deletePages invalid argument error

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I am just trying to delete pages that are after 20 if a document has more than 20 pages. This is the JS code I wrote for the Adobe Action.

```
try{

  //Get total number of pages
  var totalPages = this.numPages;

  //If it has more than 20 pages
  if(totalPages > 20) {
    this.deletePages(21, totalPages); //Delete every page from 21
    this.saveAs(this.path); //Save it
  }


} catch(e) {
   app.alert(e);
}
```

When I run the action on Adobe, I get the followin error:

> TypeError: Invalid argument type.
>   Doc.deletePages:6:Batch undefined:Exec
>   ===> Parameter nEnd.

Can anybody help me and tell me what is wrong??

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

PDF page numbers in Acrobat JavaScript are zero-based. The 21st page is page 20 so your code would be...

```
this.deletePages(20, totalPages-1);
```

Also - The example in the Acrobat JavaScript documentation for deletePages is wrong so I understand why you wrote what you wrote.